# Unable to solve Codewars problem using recursion

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a recursion solution for a [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5544c7a5cb454edb3c000047/train/python) problem. I don't see where I am going wrong. Can this problem even be solved using recursion?

```
"""
A child is playing with a ball on the nth floor of a tall building. The height of this floor, h, is known.

He drops the ball out of the window. The ball bounces (for example), to two-thirds of its height (a bounce of 0.66).

His mother looks out of a window 1.5 meters from the ground.

How many times will the mother see the ball pass in front of her window (including when it's falling and bouncing?

Three conditions must be met for a valid experiment:
Float parameter "h" in meters must be greater than 0
Float parameter "bounce" must be greater than 0 and less than 1
Float parameter "window" must be less than h.
If all three conditions above are fulfilled, return a positive integer, otherwise return -1.

Note:
The ball can only be seen if the height of the rebounding ball is strictly greater than the window parameter.

Example:
- h = 3, bounce = 0.66, window = 1.5, result is 3

- h = 3, bounce = 1, window = 1.5, result is -1

(Condition 2) not fulfilled).
"""

def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window):
    count = 1
    h = bounce * h
    if h < window:
        return count
    else:
        count += 2
        bouncingBall(h, bounce, window)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the recursive call after your else statement and you shouldn't set count to 1 every time you call the function.

```
def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window, count=1):
    h = bounce * h
    if h < window:
        return count
    else:
        count += 2
        return bouncingBall(h, bounce, window, count = count)
```

If you don't need recursion, you can also use a simple while loop.

```
def bouncingBall(h, bounce, window):
    count = -1
    while h>window and 0<bounce<1 and 0<window<h:
        h = bounce * h
        count+=2
    return count
```

Comment: Fails on code wars on the first test: testing(2, 0.5, 1, 1). Problem is also that the fourth param is given tho

Comment: The question was whether it could be solved with recursion. I have added an alternative that could pass the condititions though.

Comment: Thank you @MitchellOlislagers. I couldn't get a full pass on the recursion method but I learned where my code went wrong. Appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
def bouncing_ball(h, bounce, window):
    if h>0 and 0<bounce<1 and 0<window<h:
        c = math.log(window/h,bounce)
        return 2*int(c)-2*(c==1)+1
    return -1
```

Comment: Nope, does not give the right solution. You can check it on codewars.

Comment: You asked if this problem can be solved with recursion, which I answered. Also, I left out the check code that is obviously needed. You did not make it clear that the website you are at has particular requirements for the variables. Anyway, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I didn't ask for anything mate :p Anyhow, change my vote!

Comment: Sorry, I must have mis-read the question at the top "Can this problem even be solved using recursion?". No worries, glad I could help.